# iPad Default.png splashscreen in multitasking mode

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an iPhone application and some problems with multitasking and fast-app switching. 
When I run it on iPhone all works fine. When I runs it first time it show my Default.png image and after that my home view. I do sometheng, for example, go to another view. Then I push home button and it go in suspend mode and when i run it again it starts righ from state I leave it, without showing Default.png image.
But when I run it on iPad, it always show me Default.png image, no matter is it first run or run from suspend mode. How can I remove it like on iPhone?

UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend in Info.plist is NO.

P.S. Sorry for the bad English.

P.P.S. Of course, there are simular iOS version 4.2 on both devices.

Comment: Does your iPad supports multitasking or what is the iOS version of your iPad

Comment: Of course, there are simular iOS version 4.2 on both devices.

Comment: I think your device is not updated  check once is it updated or not

Comment: this might happen if your app is crashing in background and app is starting again..but you are saying it runs from the saved state..this is strange

Answer (score 0):

The [iOS app programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20) says :

> When the applicationDidEnterBackground: method returns, the system
>   takes a picture of your app’s user interface and uses the resulting
>   image for transition animations.

So on any device that supports multitasking, when an app is launched from the background, it would show the last screen, the user was working upon. If a device is displaying Default.png, in that case, it seems that it doesn't support multitasking. Check whether your iPad has OS version 4.2 or 3.2.

Comment: I check - it is 4.2. I also check on another iPad with 5.0.1 iOS version - same situation on it. Also I put NSLog in aplicationDidEnterBackground: method - it called. But when app runs again I still see Default.png before saved state.